# Listview.builder with stateful item is not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am getting very stange issue while using listview that having stateful items. i also explain one example here.

the example is about cart screen and every cart item has one button to remove the cart item.

The issue is that-
i have one **Listview.builder()**, and in it's **itemBuilder** - every item is another **Stateful Widget**, i am passing one **function parameter** to that widget and that widget has one **IconButton** and pressing on that i am calling that **parameter function**. and inside that function i am removing that item from the list. the item is deleted successfully from list but somehow the state is not deleting.

my code is below

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> list = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My Cart"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CartComponent(
            value: list[index],
            onDelete: () {
              setState(() {
                list.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  final Function onDelete;

  const CartComponent({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onDelete})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartComponent> createState() => _CartComponentState();
}

class _CartComponentState extends State<CartComponent> {
  String? name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    name = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "$name",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.onDelete();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the item is removed from the list successfully, and list length is also decreasing but from the view aspect, the last element of the list is being removed (but practically from the **List**, last item is not removing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your CartComponent add this:

```
final Function(String) onDelete;
```

and in press button:

```
onPressed: () {
                widget.onDelete(widget.value);
              },
```

and in ListView builder do this:

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CartComponent(
            key: UniqueKey(), // the very important part 
            value: list[index],
            onDelete: (value) {
              setState(() {
                list.remove(value);
              });
            },
          );
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `widget.value` on text `Text(widget.value,` this will work.

You can change delete function like

or

```dart
  final Function(String value) onDelete;
```

And pass value `widget.onDelete(name!);`

Now on itemBuilder

```dart
return CartComponent(
    key: ValueKey("item ${list[index]}"),
    value: list[index],
    onDelete: (v) {
      list.remove(v);
      print(v);
      setState(() {});
    },
  );
},
```

For now,

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> list = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 5",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CartComponent(
            key: ValueKey("item ${list[index]}"),
            value: list[index],
            onDelete: () {
              list.removeAt(index);
              setState(() {});
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  final Function onDelete;

  const CartComponent({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.onDelete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartComponent> createState() => _CartComponentState();
}

class _CartComponentState extends State<CartComponent> {
  String? value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    value = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                value!,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => widget.onDelete(),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so you trying to say use Name instead of ID  ???

Comment: Sorry I am using name here, cant get what do you mean by ID. key is provided to specify the unique widget

Comment: ok so what happen when we have 
List<String> list = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 5",
  ];
this kind of data same name(key) it will still works

Comment: Ok I will give you another option , if that one is easier

Comment: After testing several approaches, I am kinda confused what not to do. The thing I've found that once you change the variable widget treat that state differently,

Comment:  I've removed that, I think widget tree is getting confused by same item, and key solved the issue .

Comment: `value = widget.value;` inside `initState` is a culprit, i don't think that key is needed here

Comment: Yes, it acts differently, it behaves normal without `value`. As I knew initstate get calls before build, I thought it should not interfere.I still don't get about the widget,